# Session class not available in setUpBeforeClass

Tags: laravel-4

When my very first unit test class is run, why is the Session class not available in setUpBeforeClass?  After the first unit test class has finished, the session class is available in setUpBeforeClass.

Is there something I can do to make sure that Session is available in my first unit test?

```
<?php
class AATest extends TestCase
{

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
        \Session::put('tenantId',100);  // <-- this fails
        \Session::put('userId',1100);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        \Session::put('tenantId',100);  // <-- if removed from before class, this works.
        \Session::put('userId',1100);
    }

    public function test1()
    {
        $tenantId = \Session::get('tenantId');
        $userId = \Session::get('userId');
        $this->assertEquals(100,$tenantId);
        $this->assertEquals(1100,$userId);
    }

}
```